# For certain extremely common duplicates, it should be possible to put prominent warnings up front

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, user-interface, canonical

I just closed yet another question about an extremely common error message as a duplicate of its canonical: [Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951).

Something I've noticed about the duplicates of this question is that they almost always include the error message, or at least a very close paraphrase, in the title. (Of course, "close paraphrases" are enough to completely bewilder the site's search at times, but that's well known.)

Curious about the asker's experience, I tried going over to the Ask Question forum, and copying and pasting that duplicate's title into the title.

It gives a warning like:
[image: Many similarly phrased questions have received feedback like downvotes or requests for improvements. Consider updating your question title and body to be more descriptive.]

All well and good. However, immediately below this is a long scrolling list of... tons of other low-quality "similar" questions, most of which are probably even more (not all marked yet) duplicates.

What I **don't** see is the canonical. (Well, actually, it is in there, if I scroll far enough, but it's *way* deprioritized.)

In fact, if I start over, and copy and paste **the canonical's** title, it's third in the list of "similar questions", and there's nothing making it stand out. It has 1.9 million views, +790/-2 voting, and over 300 linked questions; but this gets summarized (in the site's visual language) as "14 answers, including an accepted answer".

How does this happen? When someone new has the same problem and puts the title in the question bar, why can't the system point out the canonical emphatically?

Even something as simple as sorting the "Similar Questions" results by score, or by duplicate-use-frequency, or by view-count would be some improvement. Highlighting some of those stats in the cases where they're impressive, might also be a good idea. And if there is a standout version of the question that **hasn't** "received feedback like downvotes or requests for improvements", but is in fact quite the opposite, maybe call attention to that in the dialog explicitly? Something like

> **This question is phrased similarly to existing popular questions.**
>
> Please check to see if your question is already answered. Otherwise, make sure in your question that it's clear why and how your question is different.

Comment: Re *"What I don't see is the canonical."*: Yes, that ought to be better than the general search engines. Perhaps there is common cause, like preferring shorter pages over longer pages (I don't know if that is actually the case; it might be completely wrong)?

Comment: If anything, sorting by score and/or viewcount would be the simplest thing that might work. Maybe the real problem is that the search results come from the Elastic Search and if they didn't include score it is probably too expensive (performance wise) to fetch that from the db for each suggested question. If I look at the network traffic, I get partial html that goes right into the DOM. I do see last activity in there but I doubt if sorting on that would have any benefit.

Comment: Ah, yes. *Of course* I should expect the fundamental problem to be architectural, baked-in, unfixable and 15 years old. This is an effort By Programmers, For Programmers after all.

Comment: Makes me wonder if there should be a "canonical" flag for answers that not only increases the value of the question but you can also filter on it in searches. How the flag gets set would be the difficult part of course, it would require a voting system tied to a minimum rep amount.

Comment: @Gimby I like how you're thinking, but that's a whole other discussion. Then again, a blue-sky redesign would presumably come up with something much smarter than a 1-dimensional "reputation" system.